# CodeLLDB for VSCode not working with remote gdbserver

Tags: arch-linux, raspbian, debugging, visual-studio-code, rust

I'm currently trying to set up remote debugging on a Raspberry Pi using the CodeLLDB plugin for Visual Studio Code and gdbserver. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, since every breakpoint I set is greyed out and the tooltip for it reads "Resolved locations: 0".

The version of CodeLLDB is `v1.7.0` and the gdbserver says it's `(Raspbian 8.2.1-2) 8.2.1`.

What makes me think that this *should* work is, that if I connect to the gdbserver manually through lldb using `target create /path/to/bin` and then `gdb-remote host:port` it works without a problem. The lldb version that works is `13.0.1`, while the CodeLLDB debugger says it's `14.0.0-custom`, so maybe that has something to do with it?

Anyway, the relevant part of the `launch.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "lldb",
  "request": "custom",
  "name": "Remote executable 'bin'",
  "preLaunchTask": "rust: remote ARM debug setup",
  "targetCreateCommands": ["target create /path/to/bin"],
  "processCreateCommands": ["gdb-remote host:port"]
}
```

Additional infos:

- The language I'm trying to debug is **rust**
- The binary was compiled for the target `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`
- I'm using VSCode on **Arch Linux**

I'm posting this half to organize what I think I know, but obviously also in hope for help. Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work after finding this useful little guide:
https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/wiki/Breakpoints-are-not-getting-hit

Using those tips I found out that lldb had located my files not in my workspace, but in some `/project/src` directory. This meant that all I had to do was add the following to my launch configuration:

```
"sourceMap": { "/project/src": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/src" }
```

Now it works like a charm. The only remaining open question for me is what that `/project/src` path means. Because while it looks like an absolute path, it isn't, since no such directory exists on my machine.

Edit: After discussing this with the friend who setup the cross-compilation for this project, he made me aware that we are using `cross`(https://github.com/cross-rs/cross) which uses a docker container during the compilation process. `/project/src` is the directory in the container that the source files are mounted to during compilation.

This also finally clears up why this additional step was necessary in the first place!